# Joomla does not find my plugin update

Tags: plugin, update

I made my first plugin and want to setup an update site as well. My joomla does not find the update (after pressing clean cache of course). The update server is found and it load my xml. My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
    <!-- UPDATESERVER DEFINITION -->
    <updateservers>
        <!-- Note: No spaces or linebreaks allowed between the server tags -->
        <server type="extension" priority="2" name="ddVmSubs">http://danidek.hu/files/ddVmSubs-update.xml</server>
    </updateservers>
</extension>
```

The update xml file (ddVmSubs-update.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updates>
    <update>
      <name>ddVmSubs</name>
      <description>Subscription plugin of Danidek for Virtuemart. </description>
      <element>ddVmSubs</element>
      <type>plugin</type>
      <folder>content</folder>
      <client>0</client>
      <client_id>0</client_id>
      <version>1.0.5</version>
        <downloads>
         <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">My download link. I removed it because I can't post more than 2 links..</downloadurl>
      </downloads>
      <tags><tag>stable</tag></tags>
      <maintainer>Danidek Inc.</maintainer>
      <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3" />
   </update>  
 </updates>
```

I can't find out what is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry it removed my xml tags. How can I add it?

Comment: Are you sure the value (`ddVmSubs`) that you have used inside the `<element>` tags match that in the `element` column in the `#__extensions` database table?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, both name and element are ddVmSubs in the extensions table.

Comment: Also, try defining the target platform version as `version="3.[678]"`

Comment: Thank you, good idea. I've changed it and still does not work (Clear cache, find updates) :-(

Comment: Also thank you for fixing my XML tags in my original post :-)

Comment: Hmm, try removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. I only say this cause I don't use it for update servers

Comment: and try changing `priority="2"` to `priority="1"`

Comment: I've tried both, but does not work :-(

Comment: I've also changed ddvmsubs to all lowercase in all files. Uninstalled it and installed it again with all lowercase. Still does not find the update...

Comment: This is what I've done last time. This is installed http://danidek.hu/files/ddvmsubs.1.0.6.zip . The update xml contains the same,but with version 1.0.7 ...

Comment: Solved thank you! After converting to lowercase the update xml uploading were goind wrong, so I updated the proper case version. After fixing the lowercase file name version it started to work! Thank you!

Comment: Please write this as a proper answer below and mark it as accepted when possible, so others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

A very important thing for me was to set these two tags:

```
<folder>content</folder>
  <client>0</client>
```

In my case, the `folder` was "hikashop", because I made a plugin for hikashop,
and the `client 0` was "Administrator", so Joomla will show the update in the back-end.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour] to earn your first badge.  Your might also like to edit your profile to tell us about who you are and your personal Joomla journey.  Please never say "thanks" or "hope this helps someone" or any other sign-offs in your posts -- these things are needless noise and should/will be trimmed by editors to improve the user experience for researchers.

Comment: You save my time after 3 days of searching.
Here are the tags you should put in your manifest

<client_id>0</client_id>
<client>0</client>
<folder>YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_IN_MY_CASE_IS_SYSTEM</folder>
<element>YOUR_ELEMENT_NAME</element>
<type>plugin</type>

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I've changed the plugin file name and element name to lowercase. It started to work.

Comment: Then please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I can accept it in 2 days...

Comment: Rrright... I forgot...

Comment: Hi! What of in the case that the plugin file name is not the same as the element name? I have this scenario for a payment gateway extension for a component. File name is 'plg_jsms_payment_paystack while element name is paystack. @Mikan and Daniel pls help